# Creating dummy variables for pairs of observations

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, grouping, dummy-variable

My dput is at the end of this prompt.

**What I’m trying to do:** I want to make two dummy variables. One is `countrypair_dummy` that is defined as follows. For each `group_number`, for every unique `AB-CD` pair in `countrypairlist` (each row already lists unique pairs, seperated by `,` , by construction) at each `Date`, set `countrypair_dummy == 1` if `countrybirthdate <= Date` and `countrydeathdate > Date` for BOTH countries in the pair.

So, for example:

Country `CZ` has `countrybirthdate == 1990-10-08` and `countrydeathdate == 1992-12-31` for `group_number == 773`.  `EP` has `countrybirthdate == 1990-10-08` and `countrydeathdate == 2004-05-01` for `group_number == 773`. Hence, for the country pair `CZ-EP` and `group_number == 773`, we have `countrydummy == 1` at all `Date`s observed in the data from `1990-10-08` until `1992-12-31`, and `countrydummy == 0`  otherwise.

The second variable---call it `country_dummy` is just like `countrypair_dummy`, except with one difference: `country_dummy == 1` if `countrybirthdate <= Date` and `countrydeathdate > Date` for EITHER countries in the pair.  Hence, for the country pair `CZ-EP` and `group_number == 773`, we have `country_dummy == 1` for all `Date` observed between `1990-10-08` until `2004-05-01`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS. I realize the first step is to do `df_1 <- separate_rows(df_1, countrypairlist, sep = ", ")`. After that, I have a hard time trying to reference the pair in R/dplyr.

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(7585L, 8338L, 7585L, 8338L, 
7645L, 7585L, 8400L, 12539L, 8338L, 8338L, 7991L, 8595L, 8012L, 
8625L, 8547L, 8012L, 8625L, 8012L, 8533L, 12539L, 8625L, 8124L, 
8124L, 8124L, 8124L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), group_number = c(773L, 
773L, 773L, 773L, 773L, 773L, 773L, 773L, 773L, 773L, 773L, 817L, 
817L, 817L, 817L, 817L, 817L, 817L, 817L, 817L, 817L, 822L, 822L, 
822L, 822L), countrybirthdate = structure(c(7585L, 7585L, 7585L, 
7585L, 7585L, 7585L, 7585L, 7585L, 7585L, 7585L, 7585L, 8012L, 
8012L, 8012L, 8012L, 8012L, 8012L, 8012L, 8012L, 8012L, 8012L, 
8124L, 8124L, 8124L, 8124L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), countrydeathdate = structure(c(12539L, 
8400L, 8400L, 19722L, 8400L, 19722L, 8400L, 12539L, 12539L, 19722L, 
12539L, 19722L, 19722L, 12539L, 12539L, 12539L, 19722L, 19722L, 
19722L, 12539L, 19722L, 19722L, 19722L, 19722L, 19722L), class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), country = c("EP", "CZ", "CZ", "DE", "CZ", "DE", 
"CZ", "EP", "EP", "DE", "EP", "DE", "DE", "EP", "EP", "EP", "DE", 
"CZ", "CZ", "EP", "CZ", "SE", "LT", "LT", "SE"), countrypairlist = c("CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", 
"CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", "CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", 
"CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", "CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", 
"CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", "CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", 
"CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", "CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", 
"CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", "CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", 
"CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", "CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", 
"CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", "CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", 
"CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", "CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", 
"CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", "CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", 
"CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", "CZ-EP, CZ-DE, CZ-SK, EP-DE, EP-SK, DE-SK", 
"LT-SE", "LT-SE", "LT-SE", "LT-SE")), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001b8b0a4b6b0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will get you close to where you need to be. My goal was to generate a data frame with the information for both countries on the same line, which greatly facilitates analysis in `dplyr`.  Note that not all of the countries are represented in the list of birth/death dates.

```r
# make a lookup table of unique group/country birth/death dates
dates <- 
  df %>% 
  select(group_number, country, countrybirthdate, countrydeathdate) %>% 
  unique()

# left_join twice to based on the countrypairlist values
df %>% 
  separate_rows(countrypairlist, sep = ", ") %>% 
  select(Date, group_number, countrypairlist) %>% 
  separate(countrypairlist, c("country", "country.x"), "-") %>% 
  left_join(dates, by = c("country", "group_number")) %>% 
  left_join(dates, by = c("country.x" = "country", "group_number")) %>% 
  mutate(
    countrypair_dummy = if_else(
      countrybirthdate.x <= Date & countrybirthdate.y <= Date & countrydeathdate.x > Date & countrydeathdate.y > Date, 1, 0),
    country_dummy = if_else(
      (countrybirthdate.x <= Date & countrydeathdate.x > Date) | (countrybirthdate.y <= Date & countrydeathdate.y > Date), 1, 0)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Crushed it. Thanks so much! As someone who's not much of a programmer, you saved me weeks of headache!!